# google sheet - search for value in 2 dimension array

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, flatten, gantt-chart, google-query-language

I am creating a Gantt Chart in Google sheet. This what it looks like: 
[image]

I add the charts manually and not using any formula. I put the name of the role and color a row in weeks that he was active.

Now I want to do some resource management calculations for every input like "Backend" role and fill a table of information like this:

```
was "Backend" active in month number 1 ? yes
How many weeks in month 1, "Backend" was active? 3
The address of "Backend's" start week: C6
The address of "Backend's" end week: E6
```

Can I do that with Formulas and not custom functions?
[Here is the link to my sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EgoSiJ71mVFP39GS7U5_Vs00eCw098DxrYDRaz79WLQ/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C22:C25,  
 QUERY(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B3:M15="backend", IF(B2:M2="",, 
 HLOOKUP(COLUMN(B1:M1), IF(B1:M1<>"", {COLUMN(B1:M1); B1:M1}), 2, 1))&"×"&1, )), "×")), 
 "select Col1,'yes',sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"), 
 "offset 1", 0), {2,3}, 0), {"no", 0}))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Third column:**

```
=ADDRESS(SUMPRODUCT((B$3:E$15=D$20)*ROW(B$3:E$15))/E22,(SUMPRODUCT((B$3:E$15=D$20)*COLUMN(B$3:E$15))-SUM(SEQUENCE(E22,1,0,1)))/E22,4)
```

**Forth column:**

```
=ADDRESS(SUMPRODUCT((B$3:E$15=D$20)*ROW(B$3:E$15))/E22,(SUMPRODUCT((B$3:E$15=D$20)*COLUMN(B$3:E$15))-SUM(SEQUENCE(E22,1,0,1)))/E22+E22-1,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

=IF(COUNTIF(B3:E15, $D$20)>0, "Yes", "No")

=COUNTIF(B3:E15, D20)

These will work for your first 2 columns, I'm following to see the cell address formula, no idea myself!